# How to watermark a Image (gif,jpeg and bmp) in visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, images, upload

When adding media for the first time, add  "staroff" watermark, approx 65% transparent, about 25% of lower
right hand corner. If possible, reject if detect watermark before uploading.

Best Regards

Comment: It is very hard to perform raw data (image etc) manipulations in apex. I would suggest you to make external service, that can do it with some libraries, and use that on image upload for check/adding watermark

Comment: Depending on your requirements you may be able to do this with javascript before a user uploads an image. External service would be easier though.

Comment: @Kasper can you please give example code

Comment: @Rajan There's a few online options if you google javascript and watermark. However, i doubt there will be many options for checking if your watermark has already been added. You could do that by running your own service (for instance with php and image magick).